# How to change the "date modified" of any file in Vista home premium?

Tags: datetime, windows-vista

In windows vista, how can i change the filed "date modified", of any file(text/binary) without editing it? I mean by just changing some of its properties.

In Win-XP if one had to change date of any file(text, binary), in the file properties menu, one could add any string in one of the fields like Author, Comment, summary and save that string. the file would show up the latest date and time as date modified. 
That is what i am looking to get in Windows Vista home premium using windows settings or registry etc, but without any third party tools/programs which need to be installed.

-Ajit

Comment: open, type a char, delete it, hit save?

Comment: @Jason: In case the file is binary, first of all it could be of large size so opening it is time consuming. Second since its binary, adding any char to it could corrupt the contents, because u might not know where u are adding it in the file etc.. so not so neat option i think,

Comment: Should this be migrated to superuser.com?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I found the following Command Prompt command](http://alexpinsker.blogspot.com/2008/06/touch-command-for-doscommand-line.html) that performs the equivalent to the Unix "touch", that will update the modified date:

```
copy /b test.txt +,,
```

Comment: @Jon: thanks it works fine. Will look if there is any alternative to it in windows itself rather than on a shell.

Comment: @jon: thanks. Used this technique for modifying mod files for a game (oblivion) so that the older mod'ed files wouldn't be overridden by the newer official game files. Not necessary, it turns out, because of an existing mod management tool, but nice to know anyways.