# Silverlight web project is always not up to date

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Silverlight web project is always not up to date. That leads to web-project rebuilding each time, even if it's never changed and it's dependencies never changed.

Is it possible to build web-project only when neccessary, not every time I start an app using VS?

Minimal build log:

> Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, <...> up-to-date, 0 skipped

Diagnostic build log:

> Project '<...>.Web' is not up to date. Input file '<...>.xap' is modified
>   after output file '<...>.Web.pdb'.

Comment: Do you take the xap file for a dependency? Here it seems it was updated, thus at least one part of the Silverlight project seems to be updated?

Comment: Yes. It looks like the web project detects that the content (XAP-file) has been changed and that triggers the building process of the server-side.

Comment: Is there an option not to rebuild a web-project until the server-side code is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be related to how MSBuild deposits xap files into a web project's ClientBin directory after it has already compiled the dll/pdb for that web project.

Something that has worked for me is to add a command-line post-build event to the web project that "touches" the pdb file, copying it into the same location. This makes the pdb have a date-modified value that is after when the xap gets pulled into the ClientBin directory.

Here's the command:

```
copy /b "$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\$(TargetName).pdb" +,,
```

Got the skeleton of the script from this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1190325/1800930

You may have to change the path, depending on what specific error you're getting.